# Wrong dropdown attribute value on the admin panel magento 2.3.5-p2

Tags: attributes, labels

I have trying to find something here but with no results. I have strange problem. We have multistore (8 views). All dropdown and multiselect attributes are global, but has different values for each store views (are translated). We keep attributes value for admin and each store view. The problem is, that when we trying to use attribute to create ex. promotion rules, on the list we see value not from admin but another store view. The same problem is on catalog->product list. When we add attribute as column normally we should see value of this attribute from admin. But we see value from the same store view as we have seen when we created promotional conditions.

How to fix this?